# Canopy editor right margin doesn't wrap text

Tags: editor, word-wrap, canopy

I've set the right margin value to 80 in Canopy editor, but the Canopy editor does not word-wrap the text in comments longer than 80 characters.  Is this normal behavior or a bug ?

Comment: I believe it is a style suggestion, but not meant to be binding.